# How to change directory in explorer using pywinauto?

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

I want to save a file in a special folder with pywinauto. The explorer folder will be opened by an another application (like if you want to save a new file in word). How can I change the path by typing the path?

With print_control_identifiers() I already had searched for the object, but I dont found it. Maybe you can help me, how the obejct is called.

Comment: Show us the code you have written so far, even if it is not yet working properly. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hey sure. 

here is the repo of my code: https://github.com/merfylive/TwitchChat_Downloader_Bot

Comment: edit: I found a workaround. I can also add the path by the file name